# Unicode in usernames (and passwords)?

Tags: php, mysql, security, unicode

[After reviewing this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470669/should-unicode-be-allowed-in-usernames) I realised I still have a few questions left regarding the topic.

Are there any characters that should be 'left out' for legitimate security purposes? This includes *all* characters, such as brackets, commas, apostrophes, and parentheses.

While on this subject, I admittedly don't understand why admins seem to enjoy enforcing the "you can only use the alphabet, numbers, and spaces" rule. Does anything else have the potential to be a security flaw or break something I'm not aware of (even in ASCII)? As far as I've seen during my coding days there is absolutely no reason that any character should be barred from being in a username.

Comment: Another possible reason is that using unicode you can sometimes make character appear the same or almost the same as some Latin-1 letter, making possible to impersonate another user. One more possible reason is it's easier to perform "search" by username if you know encoding.

Comment: I'm not particularly worried about impersonation, since like any good system user activities aren't tracked by username alone. Every user is assigned an 'id number' which can be looked at in the case of any discrepancies that may arise. In fact, the system is based more on ID number than username, to prevent this sort of thing from happening. Users have the option of searching by either UserID or username.

Comment: @Zydeco, **Re-read** your last sentence: *"Users have the option of searching by either UserID or username."* Therein lies the perfect opportunity for spoofing to happen. When users copy and paste text into that search box (*text* which they receive from online forums and chats), they press the "Search" button thinking that they are searching for the profile of that user. But they are actually being directed to User-X's profile instead which has a Unicode-spoof username of the intended user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It are often exactly those characters which can be used to inject malicious code in your program. For example [SQL injection](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html) (quotes, dashes, etc), [XSS/CSRF](http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html) (quotes, fish braces, etc) or even programming language injection when `eval()` is used elsewhere in your code.

Those characters does usually not harm when you as being the developer sanitize the user-controlled input/output properly, i.e. everything which comes in with the HTTP request; the headers, parameters and body. E.g. parameterized queries or using [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) when inlining them in a SQL query to prevent SQL injections and [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) when inlining them in HTML to prevent XSS. But I can imagine that admins don't trust all developers, so they add those restrictions.

#### See also:

- [OWASP on PHP top 5 vulrenabilities](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Top_5)

Comment: Not all sites use SQL, certainly not all that use SQL are using MySQL, so this is not a valid point. Also there are better ways to prevent XSS (prepared statements) and CSRF is completely different and has nothing to do with unicode

Comment: I am actually both admin and developer of the site that I'm creating, which is why I thought of this issue. I wanted to allow my users to be "creative" with their usernames (as well as support the ones that are actually either multilingual or hailing from different countries). Regardless of that you bought up extremely good points. What you stated was close to what I was imagining the answer might be. @Dmitri: You should notice that one of my tags is "mysql". :)

Comment: @Dmitri: the OP tagged it and it was just an example (e.g.). XSS is one of the sources of CSRF (and has nothing to do with prepared statements). And indeed this is unrelated to Unicode, I didn't imply this anywhere though.

Answer (score 5):

There's no *security reason* to not use certain characters. If you're properly handling all input, it doesn't make any difference whether you're only handling alphanumeric characters or Chinese.

It *is* easier to handle only alphnum usernames. You don't need to think about ambiguity with collations in your database, encoding usernames in URLs and things like that. But again, if you're properly handling it, there's no technical reason against it.

For practical reasons passwords are often only alphanumeric. Most password inputs don't accept IME input for example, so it's almost impossible to have a Japanese password. There's no security reason for disallowing non-alphanum characters though. On the contrary, the larger the usable alphabet, the better.

Comment: I'm somewhat torn about the passwords now, since of course I don't want my users entering "bad" passwords and not realising what they've done, but of course I'm of the same opinion that the larger the better. Any chance of a solution?

Comment: @Zydeco Maybe just display a warning along the lines of *"you may not be able to enter this password again on a different machine, please make sure you know what you're doing"* if the user entered any non-alnum characters? I would expect most people that *can* enter a non-alnum password to be aware of the implications, so I wouldn't worry about it too much. Worst case, the user can simply reset her password.

Comment: Haha. I didn't consider the "worst case scenario". ;)

Answer (score 4):

If your application handles Unicode input properly throughout, I'd certainly allow non-ASCII characters in usernames and passwords, with a few caveats:

1. If you use HTTP Basic Authentication, you *can't* properly support non-ASCII characters in usernames and passwords, because the process of passing those details involves an encode-to-bytes-in-base64 step that, currently, browsers don't agree on:

   - Safari uses ISO-8859-1, and breaks if there are any non-8859-1 characters present;
   - Mozilla uses the low byte of each character encoded to UTF-16 code units (same as ISO-8859-1 for those characters);
   - Opera and Chrome use UTF-8
   - IE uses the ANSI code page on the system it's installed on, which could be anything, but neever ISO-8859-1 or UTF-8. Characters that don't fit the encoding are arbitrarily mangled.
2. If you use cookies, you must ensure any Unicode characters are encoded in some way (eg URL-encoding), as once again trying to send non-ASCII characters gives vastly different results in different browsers.

> "you can only use the alphabet, numbers, and spaces"

You get spaces? Luxury!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a reason to not allow unicode in username. Passwords are different story, since you don't usually see password when you type it into a form, allowing only ASCII makes sense to prevent possible confusion.

I think it makes sense to use email address as the login credential rather than requiring create a new username. Then user can select any nickname, using any unicode characters and have that nick displayed next to user's posts and comments.

Isn't this how it's done on Facebook?

Comment: I can see how this would work well for Facebook, but considering half the attraction to quite a few sites are forums, and forums go by unique usernames (even if they 'spoof' others sometimes), I would have to say that isn't the best solution. The users would then be forced to remember which email they registered with (without the assistance of a 'forgot this', of course)  plus they'd need to choose a unique identifier that wasn't an email anyway. Otherwise I'd consider it a security risk (not to mention a spam one).

Comment: OpenID is a great solution to all of these problems :)

Answer (score 1):

I think that most of the time when things (usernames or passwords) are being forced down to ASCII, it's because someone is afraid that more complex character sets will cause breakage in some unknown component. Whether this fear is justified or not is case dependent, but trying to verify that your entire stack really does Unicode correctly in all cases might be difficult. It's getting better every day, but you can still find problems with Unicode in some places.

I personally keep my usernames and passwords all ASCII, and I even try not to use too much punctuation. One reason is that some input devices (like some mobile phones) make it kind of difficult to get to some of the more esoteric characters. Another reason is that I've more than once encountered a system that had no restrictions on the password contents, but then screwed up if you actually used something other than a letter or number.

Comment: So basically most admin/developers are in this simply for the sake of being lazy and not wanting to support their users from different parts of the world. ;) However as far as phones go, I'm not aware of this particular project working well with them anyway, so it's kind of moot for me and this. I can see why you'd want to take the time to mention them though. Thanks for that.

Comment: I don't know it's that bad. These days lots of people are (finally!) starting to get their Unicode act together. Unfortunately, it's still way too easy to write applications that don't do Unicode, and there's a whole lot of old software from before Unicode that has to be updated. Frankly, I can't blame folks for trying to not run into any weird new edge conditions in the software they've deployed.

Comment: Oh, it's very bad. I blame developers and admins that can't see past the ends of their English-speaking noses. Forgive me for being forward with this, but remember "www" doesn't stand for "the English speakers only" - more like "World-wide" - which happens to include languages other than the one we're using here. To me, and others, "weird, new edge conditions" might very well include being limited to one language. Of course, I can't really blame you. There are a few countries full of people that think the only real language in the world is English, so why support anything else?

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I was unclear: I wasn't saying it was OK that they were not doing these things. It's just that they aren't TRYING to lock people out. But you have to understand things from the developer's point of view: Does he put the site up with stupid limitations and starting getting users (and for a corporation, money), or does he spend an extra month or two trying to clean up issues in a stack that he may not have that much control over? It's not a good situation, but it's not that the devs are all being jerks - mostly they're just working within the limits they have.

Answer (score 1):

There is a risk involved if some parts of your program assume strings with different *bytes* are different, but other parts of the program would compare strings according to unicode semantics and think they're the same.

For example filesystems on Mac OS X enforce uniform representation of Unicode characters, so two different filenames `Ą` ('A with ogonek') and `A`+`̨` (latin A followed by 'combining ogonek') will refer to the same file.

Similarly one can produce *invalid* UTF-8 byte sequences where 1-byte codepoints are encoded usnig multiple bytes (called overlong sequences). If you normalize or reject UTF-8 input before processing it it'll be safe, but e.g. if you use Unicode-ignorant programming language and Unicode-aware database these two will see different inputs.

So to avoid that:

- You should filter UTF-8 input as early as possible. Reject invalid/overlong sequences.
- When comparing Unicode stings always convert both sides of comparison to the same Unicode Normal Form. For usernames you might want NFKD to reduce amount of homograph attacks possible.