# Umlaut issue with Windows Authentication

Tags: c#, .net, windows, authentication, windows-authentication

Is there an issue with German umlauts being read by utf-8 windows authentication? I am reading in passwords and checking the hashes by windows authentication. I have done some testing and I have confirmed that it is "ö" causing the issue in someone's password. Is this intended or could there be something I am doing incorrectly on my side?

Thanks!

Comment: Please see this entry as it does describe some reasons why this may not work.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470669/should-unicode-be-allowed-in-usernames

Comment: Windows is UTF-16. How are you passing your UTF-8 string and to which API?

Comment: Could you provide code samples for your tests?

Comment: So the issue is the way windows auth reads my MD5 hash. For some reason when it has an accent mark above a letter, it does not accept that character. I am looking into how to over come this. The code is embedded into my project pretty deep so pulling the code out would be a hassle. Going to do more research and pull the code if I have too.

Comment: This is my md5 code. Which I guess I have to change?

MD5 md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create();

            byte[] inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(pass);

            byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);

            // step 2, convert byte array to hex string

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            for (int i = 0; i < hash.Length; i++)
            {

                sb.Append(hash[i].ToString("x2"));

            }
            return sb.ToString();

Comment: Had to change from encoding to ascii to encoding to UTF8 :P 

byte[] inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pass);